# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RTNMapImage" was not found in the UIManager with React-Native android side

Tags: android, react-native

When I am trying to load a Fabric Component with a Native View I get this error : Can't create handler inside Thread:

[image]

When I reload the app I get : **Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RTNMapImage" was not found in the UIManager.**

I am not sure if those 2 errors are linked, and since I am quite new to RN I am not sure of how to solve it.

Here's my App.tsx code:

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import type {PropsWithChildren} from 'react';
    import {
      Button,
      SafeAreaView,
      ScrollView,
      StatusBar,
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      useColorScheme,
      View,
    } from 'react-native';
    
    import {
      Colors,
      DebugInstructions,
      Header,
      LearnMoreLinks,
      ReloadInstructions,
    } from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
    
    import RTNMapImage from 'rtn-map-view/js/RTNMapImageNativeComponent';
    
    
    const App: () => JSX.Element = () => {
      return (
        <RTNMapImage
          style={{width: '100%', height: 30}}
        />
      );
    };
    export default App;
```

Here is my MapView :

```kt
    package com.rtnmapview
    
    import android.content.Context
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.widget.FrameLayout
    import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext
    import com.visioglobe.visiomoveessential.VMEMapController
    import com.visioglobe.visiomoveessential.VMEMapView
    
    class MapView : FrameLayout {
      var mMapView : VMEMapView? = null
      var mMapController : VMEMapController? = null
      var mMapViewManager : MapViewManager? = null
      var filePath : String? = null
      private val context: ThemedReactContext? = null
    
      constructor(context: ThemedReactContext, mapViewManager: MapViewManager) : super(context) {
        this.mMapViewManager = mapViewManager
        this.mMapController = mapViewManager.mMapController
        this.filePath = mapViewManager.filePath
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        mMapView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_view, this, true) as VMEMapView?
        mMapView?.let { mMapController!!.loadMapData() }
        mMapView?.let { mMapController!!.loadMapView(it) }
    
      }
    
      //constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
      //}
    }
```

And the view manager :

```kt
    package com.rtnmapview
    
    import androidx.core.content.ContentProviderCompat.requireContext
    import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext
    import com.facebook.react.module.annotations.ReactModule
    import com.facebook.react.uimanager.SimpleViewManager
    import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext
    import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerDelegate
    import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp
    import com.facebook.react.viewmanagers.RTNMapImageManagerInterface
    import com.visioglobe.visiomoveessential.VMEMapController
    import com.visioglobe.visiomoveessential.VMEMapControllerBuilder
    import com.visioglobe.visiomoveessential.listeners.VMELifeCycleListener
    import org.json.JSONObject
    import java.io.File
    import java.io.FileOutputStream
    import java.io.InputStream
    
    
    @ReactModule(name = MapViewManager.NAME)
    class MapViewManager (context: ReactApplicationContext) : SimpleViewManager<MapView>(), RTNMapImageManagerInterface<MapView>{
        var filePath : String = "shizuru_regular.ttf"
        var context = context
        var mMapController : VMEMapController = VMEMapController(context, VMEMapControllerBuilder())
        private val mLifeCycleListener: VMELifeCycleListener = object : VMELifeCycleListener() {
            override fun mapDidInitializeEngine() {
                val lFilePath: String = extractFromAssetsAndGetFilePath()
                if (!lFilePath.isEmpty()) {
                    mMapController.setMapFont(lFilePath)
                } else {
                    mMapController.setMapFont(filePath)
                }
            }
    
            fun mapDataDidLoad(mapVenueInfo: JSONObject) {
                super.mapDataDidLoad()
            }
    
            override fun mapViewDidLoad() {
                super.mapViewDidLoad()
            }
    
            override fun mapDidGainFocus() {
                super.mapDidGainFocus()
            }
        }
    
        private fun extractFromAssetsAndGetFilePath(): String {
            val f: File = File( this.context.cacheDir.toString() + "/" + filePath)
            if (!f.exists()) {
                try {
                    val `is`: InputStream = this.context.assets.open(filePath)
                    val size = `is`.available()
                    val buffer = ByteArray(size)
                    `is`.read(buffer)
                    `is`.close()
                    val fos = FileOutputStream(f)
                    fos.write(buffer)
                    fos.close()
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    throw RuntimeException(e)
                }
            }
            return f.path
        }
    
    
        override fun getName(): String {
            return NAME
        }
    
        override fun getDelegate(): ViewManagerDelegate<MapView> = delegate
    
        override fun createViewInstance(p0: ThemedReactContext): MapView {
            this.mMapController.setLifeCycleListener(mLifeCycleListener);
            return MapView(context = p0, this);
        }
    
        companion object {
            const val NAME = "RTNMapViewImage"
        }
    
        @ReactProp(name = "filePath")
        override fun setFilePath(view: MapView?, value: String?) {
            if (value != null) {
                filePath = value
            }
    
        }
    
        @ReactProp(name = "mapPath")
        override fun setMapPath(view: MapView?, value: String?) {
            if (value != null) {
                mMapController.mapPath = value
            }
        }
    
        @ReactProp(name = "mapSecretCode")
        override fun setMapSecretCode(view: MapView?, value: Int) {
            if (value != null) {
                mMapController.mapSecretCode = value
            }
        }
    
        @ReactProp(name = "mapHash")
        override fun setMapHash(view: MapView?, value: String?) {
            if (value != null) {
                mMapController.mapHash = value
            }
        }
    
        @ReactProp(name = "mapServerUrl")
        override fun setMapServerUrl(view: MapView?, value: String?) {
            if (value != null) {
                mMapController.mapServerUrl = value
            }
        }
    
    }
```

The packages are exposed with this MapViewPackage:

```
    package com.rtnmapview
    
    import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage
    import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule
    import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext
    import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager
    
    class MapViewPackage : ReactPackage {
      override fun createViewManagers(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext): List<ViewManager<*, *>> =
        listOf(MapViewManager(reactContext))
        
      override fun createNativeModules(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext): List<NativeModule> =
        emptyList()
    }
```

and here is my RTNMapImageComponents.tsx for js side:

```tsx
 

    import type {ViewProps} from 'ViewPropTypes';
    import type {HostComponent} from 'react-native';
    import codegenNativeComponent from 'react-native/Libraries/Utilities/codegenNativeComponent';
    
    export interface NativeProps extends ViewProps {
        filePath : string;
        mapPath?: string; 
        mapSecretCode?: Int32; 
        mapHash?: string; 
        mapServerUrl?: string; 
      }
    
    export default codegenNativeComponent<NativeProps>(
        'RTNMapImage'
      ) as HostComponent<NativeProps>;
```

I have follow React-Native [guide](https://reactnative.dev/docs/the-new-architecture/pillars-fabric-components).

I have closed and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing

```
private val delegate = RTNMapViewManagerDelegate(this)
```

in the MapViewManager, so  `override fun getDelegate(): ViewManagerDelegate<MapView> = delegate` wasn't finding what it needs.

Comment: Could you describe your answer in a little more detail as to where was it missing from and how did you find the solution. so that other users may use your knowledge of the problem better.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me the only thing that fixed it had nothing to do with the delegate or its syntax. Surprisingly, what fixed it for me was adding

`new MyComponentPackage()`

to the list of packages in MainApplication.java!

For the record, my syntax surrounding the delegate was

```
private val delegate = MyComponentManagerDelegate(this)

override fun getDelegate() = delegate
```

I was using react native version 0.72.6